# Can a circuit have capacitors in both series and parallel?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, parallel, series, electrical

From my understanding, two capacitors (or any electrical elements) are in series if the same current goes through them. Two capacitors are in parallel if they are connected to the same wires on both ends (ie they have the same voltage across them).

If you have  a circuit with just two capacitors, and each plate of the capacitor is connected to the same wire, then aren't they both simultaneously in parallel and in series? This doesn't make sense, because which formula would you use to find equivalent capacitance then?

[image: Circuit with just two capacitors]

Comment: They are. It's a singularity, so to speak. Furthermore, you also need to decide where you want to measure across to determine equivalent capacitance.

Comment: The equivalent capacitance of this combination only matters if you hook them up to some other circuit. Once you've hooked them up, do they still meet the definition for capacitors in parallel? For capacitors in series?

Comment: The only possible arrangement of two terminals, without open circuiting a connection, means that the two capacitors are in parallel. And the same current will not, then, flow through both capacitors. Note also that current does not, strictly, flow 'through' a capacitor - the dielectric is an insulator.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think its starting to make more sense. These are indeed in both series and parallel like DKNguyen mentioned, but we don't really have to worry about equivalent resistance until we connect this two element circuit to something else, and at that point the new circuit will no longer be both in series and in parallel like The Photon was alluding to

Comment: @Chu Of course the same current will flow through both capacitors. Otherwise KCL would be violated. You can argue that the magnitude of that current, in this particular case, would be zero but that doesn't change the fact that these elements are both in series and in parallel.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson So, we're assuming an initial condition or two.

Comment: @Chu No, I am not assuming any initial conditions. I am stating that the current through the two capacitors must be the same, simply because of how they are connected together, and that the voltage across them must be the same, simply because of how they are connected together. The **magnitude** of that current and voltage is not relevant to whether they are connected in series and connected in parallel.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson if initial conditions are zero then applying a voltage source between top and bottom rails will cause different currents to flow into the capacitors

Comment: @Chu Well you changed the circuit, didn't you? I am talking about the circuit that was provided by the OP, a "circuit with just two capacitors". If you change the circuit then of course we must reconsider, but that was not part of the OP's question. Also, your original comment stating that the current through the capacitors was different said nothing about adding a source to the circuit.